# TikZ: colors stored in matrix with coordinates inferred

Tags: tikz-pgf, csv, catchfile

I'd like to use data stored in an external `CSV` file to fill nodes inside a tikzpicture matrix. If my data is stored as `x/y/z`, I can write the following loop (put together from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251300/changing-color-in-foreach) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283274/reading-the-data-to-iterate-over-with-foreach-from-a-file)):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newcommand\loaddata[1]{\CatchFileDef\loadeddata{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
1/1/20, 1/2/80, 1/3/20,
2/1/80, 2/2/100, 2/3/80,
3/1/20, 3/2/80, 3/3/20
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \loaddata{\jobname.dat}
  \foreach \x/\y/\c in \loadeddata {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\k{\c*1} % \c values could be transformed here
      \fill[color=red!\k] (\x,\y) rectangle +(1,1);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My data, instead, is stored as a matrix of `z` values (color intensities), e.g.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
20, 80, 20
80, 100, 80
20, 80, 20
\end{filecontents*}
```

Please help me adapt the code so that I can read the colors from the file and that the `x` and `y` coordinates are inferred from the cell position inside the matrix.

The tikzpicture looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to read the actual color from your dat file (`red!20`), or do you prefer it as you have it? Also not all these data needed in dat file.... just the color could be enough.

Comment: Ok... but it could be a matrix of integers with just the color value like `z_i` but without `1/1/z_1` `1/2/z_2` etc... Would this be accepted or you prefer your own dat file format?

Comment: When I posted my question, I expected that the answer would be straightforward, but as the answers of **koleygr** and **marmot** show, it involves quite a bit of trickery! On second thoughts, I could have edited my ``CSV`` file to put it in the ``x/y/z`` format and use the code that I present in the OP. In ``R``, this is one way to do it: If m is my matrix of color intensities, then ``matrix(mapply(function(x, i, j) paste0(i,"/",j,"/",x), m, row(m), col(m)), nrow = nrow(m))`` returns the matrix in the ``x/y/z`` format. But I'm glad to be learning how to do this stuff in LaTeX!

Comment: If the loaded data is quoted, e.g. ``"1/2/100"``, then sticking ``\catcode`"=9`` at the start of the tikzpicture will remove the quote marks (there may be undesirable side effects to this bulldozer approach, but it worked in this example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First version:** The size of the data matrix is known and hard-coded (here a `3 x 3` matrix):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand\loaddata[1]{\CatchFileDef\loadeddata{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
2, 8, 2,
8, 10, 8,
2, 8, 2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\def\MySpaceLength{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \loaddata{\jobname.csv}
   \foreach \k[count=\i from 0] in \loadeddata{
   \pgfmathsetmacro\myx{-3*int(\i/3)+\i}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\myy{int(\i/3)}
   \fill[color=red!\k] ({\MySpaceLength*\myx},-{\MySpaceLength*\myy}) rectangle+ ($(\MySpaceLength,\MySpaceLength)$);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second version:** the size of the matrix is known and set by the user, but not hard-coded. It is stored in the variables `\XMatrixDimension` and `\YMatrixDimension`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\newcommand\loaddata[1]{\CatchFileDef\loadeddata{#1}{\endlinechar=-1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
2, 8, 2, 5,
8, 10, 8, 90,
2, 8, 2,60,
20, 2 , 56, 40,
30, 20, 50, 70
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\def\MySpaceLength{3}
\def\XMatrixDimension{4}
\def\YMatrixDimension{5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \loaddata{\jobname.csv}
   \foreach \k[count=\i from 0] in \loadeddata{
   \pgfmathsetmacro\myx{-\XMatrixDimension*int(\i/\XMatrixDimension)+\i}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\myy{int(\i/\XMatrixDimension)}
   \fill[color=red!\k] ({\MySpaceLength*\myx},-{\MySpaceLength*\myy}) rectangle+ ($(\MySpaceLength,\MySpaceLength)$);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer koleygr. I think I understand the steps. I'll play around with this a little and get back to you if I get stumped. Perhaps I should have considered making a CSV of my data (obtained with ``R``) in the ``1/2/3`` format. Might have been easier. That said, it's good to learn how to do this with ``LaTeX``! Thanks.

Comment: For your second version, I think that ``\pgfplotstablegetelem`` can be used to calculate the dimension of the matrix, such that it would not have to be set by the user at all, something similar to what marmot does in their answer and/or similar to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343770/pgfplotstablegetelem-problem

Comment: @PatrickT, Nice addition and very nice edit. But instead of using a huge package (`pgfplots`) just to avoid one or two copy pastes is not recommended. If you want to use this functionality many times and you dont want just to copy paste the matrix and change any `//` with comma, then the way is what you already mentioned. So, the comment is useful

Comment: indeed good point about not loading a package that is not absolutely needed. My purpose has been served, so I thank you and shall accept your answer, as it came before marmot's, whose answer relies on the ``pgfplots`` package and is also very commendable! :-)

Comment: Thanks. marmot has my vote now because I just learned some pgf

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on matrix plot that comes with pgfplots. It is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446032/121799), whose second part has some similarity with [koleygr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450837/121799). The advantage of the pgfplots solution is that you can use color maps for that. Of course, you can drop the colorbar.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
2, 8, 2
8, 10, 8
2, 8, 2
\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false,col sep=comma]{\jobname.csv}\datatable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval}
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numcols}{\pgfplotsretval}
\xdef\LstX{}
\xdef\LstY{}
\xdef\LstC{}
\foreach \Y [evaluate=\Y as \PrevY using {int(\Y-1)},count=\nY] in {1,...,\numrows}
{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newY}{\numrows-\Y}
\foreach \X  [evaluate=\X as \PrevX using {int(\X-1)},count=\nX] in {1,...,\numcols}
{
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\PrevY}{\PrevX}{\Current}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nZ}{\nX+\nY}
\ifnum\nZ=2
\xdef\LstX{\PrevX}
\xdef\LstY{\PrevY}
\xdef\LstC{\Current}
\else
\xdef\LstX{\LstX,\PrevX}
\xdef\LstY{\LstY,\PrevY}
\xdef\LstC{\LstC,\Current}
\fi
}
}
\edef\temp{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{
 create on use/x/.style={create col/set list={\LstX}},
 create on use/y/.style={create col/set list={\LstY}},
 create on use/color/.style={create col/set list={\LstC}},}}
\temp
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\strangenum}{\numrows*\numcols}
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={x,y,color}]{\strangenum}\strangetable

%\pgfplotstabletypeset[empty cells with={---}]\strangetable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{%
    colormap={WhiteRedBlack}{%
        rgb255=(255,255,255)
        rgb255=(255,0,0)
        rgb255=(0,0,0)
    },
}
\begin{axis}[%
    small,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
    tick align=outside,
    minor tick num=5,
    %
    xlabel=$\beta$,
    xticklabel pos=right,
    xlabel near ticks,
    xmin=-1, xmax=\numcols,
    xtick={0, 5, ..., 4},
    %
    ylabel=$\alpha$,
    ylabel style={rotate=-90},
    ymin=-1, ymax=\numrows,
    ytick={0, 5, ..., 4},
    %
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=32,
    point meta=explicit,
    %
    %colorbar sampled,
    colorbar as palette,
    colorbar style={samples=3},
    colormap name=WhiteRedBlack,
    scale mode=scale uniformly,
]
\draw (axis description cs:0,0) -- (axis description cs:1,0);
 \addplot [
        matrix plot,
        %mesh/cols=4,
        point meta=explicit,
] table [meta=color,col sep=comma] \strangetable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer marmot. I'm going to need to play around with this a little to digest it. I've started reading the links, very useful. Quite frankly, I did not expect that changing the format of the data would induce so much extra work. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT It could very well be that I missed a simple possibility... In case you find out, please ping me. ;-)

Comment: Yours is an excellent answer and I have learned (and am still learning) quite a lot about the ``pgfplots`` package. I like how all the computations are automated. It was a difficult decision, but I selected koleygr's answer as it came first and is a little simpler (though not quite as general as yours). Thanks again!

Comment: @PatrickT Yes, you should accept koleygr's answer. I can't help to note that the second part of my old answer is rather similar to his, and I would have wished he would have acknowledged this. Don't get me wrong, I think it is fine to reuse existing answers, but it would be nice to mention them when doing that.